# Нужен ли nginx, если статика на cdn

Tags: nginx, apache, cdn

Есть сервер со связкой Nginx+Apache. Сайты на сервере работают на Wordpress.

Статику планируем выносить в S3 хранилище с cdn (digitalocean). И возникает вопрос - нужен ли тогда в принципе nginx или хватит и Apache. Возможно, Nginx лучше подходит для оптимизации чего-либо еще, кроме статики?

Comment: Если вопрос по статике, то метка WordPress тут ни при чём. nginx держит более высокие нагрузки, он специально создавался, чтобы решить проблему 10к (10 тыс запросов в секунду).

Comment: Я бы вообще не использовал Apache

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете nginx только ради статики, а вся динамика все равно уходит в Apache - то нет, не нужен.

Если вы на nginx делаете SSL Offloading, или добрасываете заголовки - то нужен.